# Place Autocomplete is not properly working

Tags: android, api, maps

I am using place autocomplete new sdk in my project.

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'

> Autocompletetextview : I am using it to show data.The problem is that
>   it works correctly for the first time not second time.The list does not show on the
>   second time and the address of someone. sometime i get error
>   :PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter: Place not found: 9010.
>   Please help to solve this issue.

```
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapterNew extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {
        PlacesClient placesClient;
        AutocompleteSessionToken token;
        private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        private List<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;
        private List<AutocompletePrediction> tempResult;
        Context context;
        private String TAG = "PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter";

        public PlaceAutocompleteAdapterNew(Context context, PlacesClient placesClient, AutocompleteSessionToken token) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
            this.context = context;
            this.placesClient = placesClient;
            this.token = token;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (mResultList == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return mResultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
            return mResultList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                        mResultList = getAutoComplete(constraint);
                        if (mResultList != null) {
                            // The API successfully returned results.
                            results.values = mResultList;
                            results.count = mResultList.size();
                        }
                    }
                    return results;

                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                    // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                    // when clicked.
                    if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                        return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                    } else {
                        return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private List<AutocompletePrediction> getAutoComplete(CharSequence constraint) {
            // Create a new token for the autocomplete session. Pass this to FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest,
            // and once again when the user makes a selection (for example when calling fetchPlace()).
            // AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
            // Create a RectangularBounds object.

            // Use the builder to create a FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.
            FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                    .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                    .setSessionToken(token)
                    .setQuery(constraint.toString())
                    .build();

            placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse response) {
                    for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());
                    }
                    tempResult = response.getAutocompletePredictions();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                    }
                }
            });
            return tempResult;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code suggest an issue with places api billing, code 9010 means that you exceeded the query limits allowed by your billing.
Places autocomplete is not free, but Google lets you try it a few times without a billing account set before denying requests.

Comment: My billing account active now code is working.@R.wurf Thanks .